# connect to node server finding the mask automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, lan

so this is my problem:
I have a node server with a game i'm creating. the node server is listening in a ip mask that is given to him in network, like 192.168.x.x (isn't always the same).
The game 'frontend' is a web page, in a domain (like paperplane.io) that points to my dropbox project and makes it accessible.
How can I make my game frontend, the client, know behind what mask is node server listning, in that network, so it can communicate with it with no specific configuration.
Synthesizing: start node server in local network. every device in that network can access it via web url. plug & play.

thaks

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the question. So, you have a node server running in a local network (192.168.x.x), and you want any user (publicly) to be able to visit that server via a domain name? EG: paperplane.io? Is this correct?

Comment: sorry if i'm not making myself very clear! Any user connected in my network. the web page is online for everybody. but the game will only work if a node server is detected in local network. is it clearer this way?

Comment: Ah, I see. So public users visit this site, but only if a game server is on the LAN the person can play -- correct?

Comment: exactly like that :) but i have to detect the server automatically because it can change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i solved my problem by having my node server sending updates to a mysql database with something like: I'm XPTO and I'm at 192.169.X.XX.
so, when i access my application i tell her what i'm looking for (i always know) like this:
XPTO.application.com
by the subdomain i check the database for key:value and get my nodejs ip mask in network.